# Multiple Google drive accounts

Tags: google-account

I have two Google drive accounts.I have downloaded Google drive once.But I can use only one account with it for sync files.

How can I use another account for sync files in one computer? Whether I have to download Google Drive again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Drive to manage first account then use a Cloud Storage Manager application like cloudfuze.com or any other you can find using your favorite search engine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.But I don't want to use any extra stuff like cloud with it.So is there any other way I could do this?

Comment: Ok I found the solution....we can disconnect the first account from the Google drive by clicking on the Google Drive icon in the right side bottom of the screen then go to Settings  -> Preferences -> Account tab -> then disconnect the account........then connect the other account & we can sync files by creating another folder or in the same that was created for the first account its that much easy.

Comment: I was looking to solve the same problem, it was not exactly what I wanted, but it is the best option that I found without installing a third software.